# Javascript how to check if a date is greater than or equal to a date value

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to see if the date value is set to today's date or greater.

```
var date = document.getElementById("inputDate").value;
var varDate = new Date(date); //dd-mm-YYYY
var today = new Date();

if(varDate >= today) {
//Do something..
alert("Working!");
}
```

Date format dd-mm-YYYY

The current code above won't work.

Comment: please explain what values you want to compare - `today` is misnamed - thats more like `now` including time, not just the date.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you only want to compare **Date** and not **Date-Time** then add this line

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

before comparison.